# Does Netbeans 6.0.1 support JCAPS or do I have to download netbeans 6.1?

Tags: java, netbeans, jcaps

I am bit confused no how to use JCAPS. I have Netbeans 6.0.1. Is it necessary to have Netbeans 6.1 to use JCAPS?

Secondly how do I use JCAPS?

I am new to Java so hopefully I'll find good support here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JCAPS (6.1 at least) is intimately tied to Netbeans 6.1 and Glassfish 2.1; you've got no other choice than using what is installed by JCAPS.

Maybe you should try to learn the basis of Java SE programming, and Java-ee packaging (concept of EAR files) and deployment before investigating JCAPS

Comment: +1 for good general suggestions. Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481475/jcaps-little-boxes-of-hell) before?

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091959/any-jcaps-tutorials